# Add a new field to the sympy symbolic variable

Tags: python, sympy

I have a SymPy symbolic variable:

```
from sympy import symbols 
x=symbols('x')
```

How can I add a new field to the symbolic variable `x`?

```
x.New_Field=Arbitrary_Value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *cannot* dynamically add an attribute to a `Symbol`.

It would most likely be a bad idea because SymPy assumes that it can replace expressions which compare as equal. So if you created two symbols and stored an attribute dynamically in one (*supposing this were possible*)

```
a1 = Symbol('a') 
a2 = Symbol('a') 
a1.something = 0
```

Then SymPy would take the liberty of swapping `a1` and `a2` whenever it felt like doing so as they compare equal (`a1 == a2`), which would certainly have unintended consequences.

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/symbol.py), you can see that a `Symbol` defines `__slots__` in its class for performance reasons, which effectively tells the interpreter "*These are all the instance attributes in this class*". This is *why* you cannot dynamically add attributes to a `Symbol`.

A possible alternative could be to create a subclass of `Symbol` that stores your desired attributes in its `args`, such that they are factored into  the equality comparison of your subclass objects.

---

*For an extended discussion on the topic which I somewhat paraphrased here, see the Google thread: [How to equip a Symbol with an additional attribute?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/vDvCLZYeKoQ)*